# How to write additional methods in Smalltalk Collections which work only for Numeric Inputs?

Tags: smalltalk

I want to add a method "average" to array class.
But average doesn't make any sense if input array contains characters/strings/objects.
So I need to check if array contains only integers/floats.

Smalltalk says datatype check [checking if variable belongs to a particular datatype like int string array etc... or not] is a bad way of programming.

So what is best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specification is somewhat incomplete. You'd need to specify what behavior the collection should show when you use it with non-numeric input.
There are a huge number of possibly desirable behaviors. Smalltalk supports most of them, except for the static typing solution (throw a compile-time error when you add a non-numeric thing to a numeric collection).

- If you want to catch non-numeric objects as late as possible, you might just do nothing - objects without arithmetic methods will signal their own exceptions when you try arithmetic on them.
- If you want to catch non-numeric elements early, implement a collection class which ensures that only numeric objects can be added (probably by signaling an exception when you add a non-numeric object is added).
- You might also want to implement "forgiving" methods for sum or average that treat non-numeric objects as either zero-valued or non-existing (does not make a difference for #sum, but for #average you would only count the numeric objects).

Comment: I'd avoid the third option, it feels like a recipe for enabling sloppy code, like what you get when you start using `nil` instead of a proper  Null Object as a domain value.

Comment: A middle ground between the first and second would be to allow non-numeric elements, but convert the `MessageNotUnderstood` exceptions to be more explicit in the context of aggregate behavior like `#sum` or `#average`.

Comment: Actually, there's only one GOOD way to do it. And it is the first option that @Hans-Martin suggested. That's the only way you'll preserve polymorphism.

If it doesn't make sense to send #sum: to a collection of not-numbers, just don't send it. If you have numbers and characters, then the problem is before of the #sum:

It is very common to implement #sum:, #average: and other aggregate like methods. And I never saw one implementation doing a type check before.

Comment: Yes, after good searching, I too realized that Exception Handling is the only better way. Well creating a special Collection class also makes a good alternative.
But given that I am newbie, I prefer to keep it simple for now.

Answer (score 3):

In [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) at least there is

```
Collection >> average
^ self sum / self size
```

In `Collections-arithmetic` category. When you work with with a statically typed languages you are being hit by the language when you add non-number values to the collection. In dynamically typed languages you the same happens when you try to calculate average of inappropriate elements e.i. you try to send `+`, `-` or `/` to an object that does not understand it.

Don't think where you put data, think what are you doing with it.

It's reasonable to check type if you want to do different things, e.g.:

```
(obj isKindOf: Number) ifTrue: [:num| num doItForNum].
(obj isKindOf: Array ) ifTrue: [:arr| arr doItForArr].
```

But in this case you want to move the logic of type checking into the object-side.

So in the end it will be just:

```
obj doIt.
```

and then you'll have also something like:

```
Number >> doIt
    "do something for number"

Array >> doIt
    "do something for array"
```

(brite example of this is `printOn:` method)

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought the Smalltalk answer would be to implement it for numbers, then be mindful not to send a collection of pets #sum or #average.  Of course, if there later becomes a useful implementation for a pet to add itself to another pet or even an answer to #average, then that would be up to the implementer of Pet or PetCollection.

I did a similar thing when I implemented trivial algebra into my image.  It allowed me to mix numbers, strings, and symbols in simple math equations.  2 * #x result in 2x.  x + y resulted in x + y.  It's a fun way to experiment with currencies by imagining algebra happening in your wallet.  Into my walled I deposit (5 x #USD) + (15 * #CAN) for 5USD + 15CAN.  Given an object that converts between currencies I can then answer what the total is in either CAN or USD.

We actually used it for supply-chain software for solving simple weights and measures.  If a purchase order says it will pay XUSD/1TON of something, but the supplier sends foot-lbs of that same thing, then to verify the shipment value we need a conversion between ton and foot-lbs.  Letting the library reduce the equation we're able to produce a result without molesting the input data, or without having to come up with new objects representing tons and foot-pounds or anything else.

I had high ambitions for the library (it was pretty simple) but alas, 2008 erased the whole thing...

Comment: Do you know about the Aconcagua package for Pharo, that implements units (physics and currencies) and their arithmetics?

Answer (score 0):

"I want to add a method "average" to array class. But average doesn't make any sense if input array contains characters/strings/objects. So I need to check if array contains only integers/floats."

There are many ways to accomplish the averaging of the summation of numbers in an Array while filtering out non-numeric objects.

First I'd make it a more generic method by lifting it up to the Collection class so it can find more cases of reuse. Second I'd have it be generic for numbers rather than just floats and integers, oh it'll work for those but also for fractions. The result will be a float average if there are numbers in the collection array list.

(1) When adding objects to the array test them to ensure they are numbers and only add them if they are numbers. This is my preferred solution.

(2) Use the Collection #select: instance method to filter out the non-numbers leaving only the numbers in a separate collection. This makes life easy at the cost of a new collection (which is fine unless you're concerned with large lists and memory issues). This is highly effective, easy to do and a common solution for filtering collections before performing some operation on them. Open up a Smalltalk and find all the senders of #select: to see other examples.

```
| list numberList sum average |
list := { 100. 50. 'string'. Object new. 1. 90. 2/3. 88. -74. 'yup' }.
numberList := list select: [ :each | each isNumber ].
sum := numberList sum.
average := sum / (numberList size) asFloat.
```

Executing the above code with "print it" will produce the following for the example array list:

```
 36.523809523809526
```

However if the list of numbers is of size zero, empty in other words then you'll get a divide by zero exception with the above code. Also this version isn't on the Collection class as an instance method.

(3) Write an instance method for the Collection class to do your work of averaging for you. This solution doesn't use the select since that creates intermediate collections and if your list is very large that's a lot of extra garbage to collect. This version merely loops over the existing collection tallying the results. Simple, effective. It also addresses the case where there are no numbers to tally in which case it returns the nil object rather than a numeric average.

Collection method: #computeAverage

```
"Compute the average of all the numbers in the collection. If no numbers are present return the nil object to indicate so, otherwise return the average as a floating point number."

| sum count average |
sum := 0.
count := 0.
self do: [ :each |
     each isNumber ifTrue: [
        count := count +1.
        sum := sum + each.  
    ]
].
count > 0 ifTrue: [ 
    ^average := sum / count asFloat
] ifFalse: [ 
    ^nil
]
```

Note the variable "average" is just used to show the math, it's not actually needed.

You then use the above method as follows:

```
| list averageOrNil |
list := { 100. 50. 'string'. Object new. 1. 90. 2/3. 88. -74. 'yup' }.
averageOrNil := list computeAverage.
averageOrNil ifNotNil: [ "got the average" ] ifNil: [ "there were no numbers in the list"
```

Or you can use it like so:

```
{ 
    100. 50. 'string'. Object new. 1. 90. 2/3. 88. -74. 'yup' 
} computeAverage 
    ifNotNil: [:average | 
        Transcript show: 'Average of list is: ', average printString 
    ] 
    ifNil: [Transcript show: 'No numbers to average' ].
```

Of course if you know for sure that there are numbers in the list then you won't ever get the exceptional case of the nil object and you won't need to use an if message to branch accordingly.

---

Data Type/Class Checking At Runtime

As for the issue you raise, "Smalltalk says datatype check [checking if variable belongs to a particular datatype like int string array etc... or not] is a bad way of programming", there are ways to do things that are better than others.

For example, while one can use #isKindOf: Number to ask each element if it's not the best way to determine the "type" or "class" at runtime since it locks it in via predetermined type or class as a parameter to the #isKindOf: message.

It's way better to use an "is" "class" method such as #isNumber so that any class that is a number replies true and all other objects that are not numeric returns false.

A main point of style in Smalltalk when it comes to ascertaining the types or classes of things is that it's best to use message sending with a message that the various types/classes comprehend but behave differently rather than using explicit type/class checking if at all possible.

The method #isNumber is an instance method on the Number class in Pharo Smalltalk and it returns true while on the Object instance version it returns false.

Using polymorphic message sends in this away enables more flexibility and eliminates code that is often too procedural or too specific. Of course it's best to avoid doing this but reality sets in in various applications and you have to do the best that you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the kind of thing you do in Smalltalk. You could take suggestions from the above comments and "make it work" but the idea is misguided (from a Smalltalk point of view).

The "Smalltalk" thing to do would be to make a class that could perform all such operations for you --computing the average, mean, mode, etc. The class could then do the proper checking for numerical inputs, and you could write how it would respond to bad input. The class would use a plain old array, or list or something. The name of the class would make it clear what it's usage would be for. The class could then be part of your deployment and could be exported/imported to different images as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new collection class; perhaps a subclass of `Array`, or perhaps of `OrderedCollection`, depending on what collection related behaviour you want.

In the new class' `at:put:` and/or `add:` methods test the new item for `#isNumber` and return an error if it fails.

Now you have a collection you can guarantee will have just numeric objects and nils. Implement your required functions in the knowledge that you won't need to deal with trying to add a Sealion to a Kumquat. Take care with details though; for example if you create a `WonderNumericArray` of size 10 and insert two values into it, when you average the array do you want to sum the two items and divide by two or by ten?